# Finding matching suggestions with multiple records from different "users"

Tags: mysql, aggregate, pattern-matching

I'm not even entirely sure how to phrase my question because it is rather complicated. I am trying to implement a feature that will help crowd source information for one of our systems, and the system should validate these "suggestions" automatically. There are certain criteria that determine a "valid" suggestion:

1. 3 suggestions
2. 3 different "users"
3. Same combination of "adaptors"

For example, Tom works for Acme Co. and suggests using Adaptor A + Adaptor B for this particular scenario. Likewise, Jon works for Acme Inc. and suggests the same Adaptor A + Adaptor B for this particular scenario. Finally, Bob works for Acme Enterprises, and he too suggests the same Adaptor A + Adaptor B for this particular scenario.

Upon Bob submitting his suggestion, the system would be able to determine that there are 2 matching suggestions from 2 different companies, constituting a valid suggestion, and would then perform some action (this action is outside of the scope of this issue).

What I have done so far is create a table to store suggestions:

id 
user_id
vehicle_id
service_id

Each suggestion may have one or more "adaptors" so I am using a pivot table:

suggestion_id
adaptor_id

Finally, because we are really concerned about the "company" the user works for (remember suggestions are only considered valid if they come from 3 different companies), so I have composed a view to join this information:

suggestion_id
user_id
company_id
vehicle_id
service_id
adaptor_id

Here is an example of what some of this data would look like:

[image]

The highlighted rows a potentially valid suggestion, with the exception that the suggestions from company 58 should only be counted as 1 suggestion because they come from the same company. Furthermore, suggestion 87 only contains 1 of the adaptors found in the other 2 matching suggestions. If suggestion 87 included both adaptor id 669 and 936, these suggestions would be considered valid.

My question is how to query this information? I currently am trying something like this:

```
select distinct 
`company_id`, 
`vehicle_id`, 
`service_id`, 
`adaptor_id` 
from `service_guide_suggestions` 
where `user_id` != 2 
and `company_id` != 1 
and `vehicle_id` = 30149
and `service_id` = 3
and `adaptor_id` in (669,936)
```

I need to be able to answer some question as "Do we have at least 3 suggestions for the same vehicle and service, from 3 different companies, with matching adaptors?"

My apologies if my question is not clear or is lacking enough information. I'm happy to provide as many details as possible for any feedback. Many thanks!

**UPDATE**
Trying danblack's suggestion yields these results:
[image]

Comment: `SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(adapter_id) FROM tbl GROUP BY vehicle_id,service_id HAVING count(distinct company_id) > 3` maybe.  Or is `adapter_id` part of the `GROUP`. Switching from 'widgets' to 'adapters' part way though story detracts from clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies for the inconsistency. I changed "widgets" to adaptors. To answer your question, the specific combination of adaptors for each suggestion constitutes the group. I updated the original question with a screenshot of the results from your query. I don't believe this is going to be it though. We know that a valid suggestion will be 2-3 adaptors at most. Curious what other ideas you have?